# Best way to deal with a trailing comma when using X macros in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c-preprocessor

What's the best way to deal with extra trailing commas when working with X macros?  Specifically, I have the following setup in a file `test01.cpp`

```c++
struct Foo {
    #define X(name,val) int name;
    #include "test01.def"
    #undef X

    Foo() :
        #define X(name,val) name(val),
        #include "test01.def"
        #undef X
    {}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
}
```

In `test01.def`, I have

```c++
X(foo,1)
X(bar,23)
```

This doesn't compile because of the error

```
test01.cpp: In constructor 'Foo::Foo()':
test01.cpp:10:5: error: expected identifier before '{' token
     {}
```

Basically, there's a trailing comma after the last element in the member initializer list.  Now, we can fix this by adding a dummy variable:

```c++
struct Foo {
private:
    void * end;
public:
    #define X(name,val) int name;
    #include "test01.def"
    #undef X

    Foo() :
        #define X(name,val) name(val),
        #include "test01.def"
        #undef X
        end(nullptr)
    {}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
}
```

However, this is sort of ugly.  As such, is there a better way to handle the trailing comma in the member initializer list?

---

## Edit 1

Here's another option that's still kind of ugly:

```c++
struct Foo {
    #define X(name,val) int name;
    #include "test01.def"
    #undef X

    Foo() :
        #define X(name,val) name(val),
        #define XLAST(name,val) name(val)
        #include "test01.def"
        #undef XLAST
        #undef X
    {}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
}
```

along with

```c++
#ifndef XLAST
    #define XLAST X
    #define CLEANUP
#endif

X(foo,1) 
XLAST(bar,23)

#ifdef CLEANUP
    #undef XLAST
    #undef CLEANUP
#endif
```

Basically, we define the macro `XLAST` to take care of the final comma.  If we use `XLAST`, we have to manually undefine it like `X`, but we do this automatically in the case that we don't define it explicitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've tagged this C++14, the easiest way to solve this problem is to use [*brace-or-equal-initializer*s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) instead of the `mem-initializer`s.

```
struct Foo {
    #define X(name,val) int name = val;
    #include "test01.def"
    #undef X

    // Foo() {} // uncomment if you do not want Foo to be an aggregate
};
```

---

If you want to stick with a preprocessor solution, you can use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to do this. You'll need to change the format of your data member definitions so it forms a [*sequence*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html).

```
#define FOO_MEMBERS ((int,i,10)) ((long,j,20))
```

I added the ability to specify arbitrary data types too.

First let's declare and initialize these data members

```
struct Foo
{
    #define OP(s, data, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, elem) \
                              BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem) = \
                              BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, elem);
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(OP, , FOO_MEMBERS)
    // expands to 
    //      int i = 10; long j = 20;
    #undef OP

    Foo() = default;  // default constructor
};
```

[BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) will expand the macro `OP` for each element in the sequence `FOO_MEMBERS`.

[`BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/tuple_elem.html) simply extracts a single element from its *tuple* argument.

Next, let's give `Foo` a constructor that takes arguments corresponding to each data member and initializes it.

```
#define OP(s, data, elem) (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem))
Foo(
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(OP, , FOO_MEMBERS))
    // expands to
    //      int i, long j
) :
#undef OP

#define OP(s, data, elem) (BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem)(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, elem)))
BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(OP, , FOO_MEMBERS))
// expands to
//      i(i), j(j)
#undef OP
{}
```

We use [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_enum.html) to generate a comma separated list from the result of the expansion of `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eccbe034d7fc1114)

Comment: I do intend to use C++14 and I like this trick.  Nevertheless, if I end up requiring something more than the default constructor, is there a good way to handle this?  For example, say we want to pass in an integer to the constructor and set both `foo` and `bar` to the specified value.

Comment: @wyer33 See updated answer. And just to be clear, the original solution doesn't require C++14, only C++11. The difference between the two standards is that, as written in the first example, `Foo` is not an aggregate in C++11 due to the presence of the data member initializers, but C++14 changed this rule so that it is an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `end` to be of [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) type the compiler is likely to optimize it and remove it. And the intent is clear to the reader.

```
 struct Foo {
private:
 static std::nullptr_t end;
```

alternatively, you might declare `char end[0];` (this won't use any space) but some compilers might reject that.

Of course, as [Pratorian answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002431/841108), you could use some X-macro friendly construct instead.

Comment: does any compiler actually remove class members that are unused (after whole-program analysis presumably)

Comment: GCC used to probably do that (but you had to use some weird `-f` optimization flags). It had even a pass which reordered members in structures and classes. That has been removed (perhaps in 4.7)

Comment: maybe you could add an empty base class (although then you have to live with warning about initializers being out of order)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for a solution not involving a dependency on BOOST_PP, a preprocessor-based alternative, also useful for plain-old C, is to deal with a *leading* comma using the preprocessor, which is much easier than dealing with a *trailing* comma.

```
/// Indirection macro, so that macro expansion of parameters is done before token pasting.
#define REMOVE_FIRST(...) REMOVE_FIRST_SUB(__VA_ARGS__)

/// Paste all parameters but first.
#define REMOVE_FIRST_SUB(X, ...) __VA_ARGS__

#define FOO_DEF(X) \
  X(foo,1) \
  X(bar,23)

struct Foo {
    #define X(name,val) int name;
    FOO_DEF(X)
    #undef X

    Foo() :
        #define X(name,val) ,name(val)
        REMOVE_FIRST(FOO_DEF(X))
        #undef X
    {}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
}
```

Testing:

```
$ gcc -E test.c
# 0 "test.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 11 "test.c"
struct Foo {

    int foo; int bar;


    Foo() :

        foo(1) ,bar(23)

    {}
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
}
```